# Inequality involving log functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, logarithms, convex-analysis

> How does $k\log(n)$ compares with $k_1 \log(n_1) +k_2 \log(n_2)$ where $k=k_1+k_2$ and $n=n_1+n_2$?.

It is given that $k_1,k_2,n_1,n_2$ are positive integers

To me it seems like $k\times log (n)$ is always greater. But, I am unable to find a way to prove this. The same question can be posed as $$(n_1+n_2)^{k_1+k_2}\ \ \  \text{ VS }\ \ \ n_1^{k_1} \times n_2^{k_2}$$

Could you please provide any insights?

Edit: We also know $n_1>>k_1$ and $n_2>>k_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Binomial Theorem:

$$(n_1+n_2)^{k_1+k_2} = \sum_{j=0}^{k_1+k_2} \binom {k_1+k_2}j n_1^j n_2^{k_1+k_2-j} > \binom {k_1+k_2}{k_1}n_1^{k_1}n_2^{k_2}$$

since $k_1,k_2,n_1,n_2 > 0$.